# Uploading android module to bintray and linking to jcenter

Tags: android, gradle, bintray, jcenter

Hi so I'm following the github site of Gradle Bintray Plugin https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin#readme tutorial however I don't quite understand the publications part. Can anyone help me with this? I'am currently working on bintray version 1.7.3.

Update:
I was able to upload successfully in bintray. However my current problem now is when downloading it in other projects. I have errors when syncing gradle :

-Could not find android-dbpatcher.jar(sirqo:android-dbpatcher:0.0.1).

-Error: Searched in the following locations:

http://sirqo.bintray.com/Android-DBPatcher/sirqo/android-dbpatcher/0.0.1/android-dbpatcher-0.0.1.jar

Update2:
For reference this is my gradle.build in my module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-  core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath +=         project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

group = 'xxxx'
version = '0.0.1'

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.project {
            name 'android-dbpatcher'
            description 'A library for updating SQLite database in android.'
            url 'https://sirqo.bintray.com/Android-DBPatcher'
            inceptionYear '2016'

            packaging 'aar'
            groupId 'xxxx'
            artifactId 'android-dbpatcher'
            version '0.0.1'

            licenses {
                license {
                    name "The Apache Software License, Version 2.0"
                    url "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt"
                    distribution "repo"
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id  'xxxx'
                    name 'xxxxx'
                    email 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Properties bintrayProperties = new Properties()
    bintrayProperties.load(project.rootProject.file('bintray.properties').newDa    taInputStream())

bintray {
    user = bintrayProperties.getProperty('user')
    key = bintrayProperties.get('key')
    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = 'Android-DBPatcher'
        name = 'android-dbpatcher'
        userOrg = 'xxxx'
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/sirqo/android-dbpatcher'
        publish = true
        version {
            name = '0.0.1'
            desc = 'Android SQLite Database Patcher'
            released = new Date()
            vcsTag = 'v0.0.1'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/technology/developer-blog/2016/dec/06/how-to-publish-an-android-library-a-mysterious-conversation

Comment: http://crushingcode.co/publish-your-android-library-via-jcenter/

Comment: thanks @Basi ill try this out.

Comment: @basi I have a question, what is this for  // Place it at the end of the file
 apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nisrulz/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
 apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nisrulz/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'

Comment: its from http://crushingcode.co/publish-your-android-library-via-jcenter/

Comment: it contains pre-define code, please go through it you will understand

Comment: @basi I was able to upload it a while ago in bintray. However I got error Failed to resolve:sirqo:android-dbpatcher:0.0.1

Comment: are you linked lib to jcenter?

Comment: @Basi not yet. But I added my repository in the project level gradle.build

Comment: @Basi i forgot I don't see the button link to JCenter inside my package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out. For reference I'll share my code.

For my Project gradle.build

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.7.3"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And for my module gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath +=project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

group = 'xxxx' //bintray org/group name
version = '0.0.1' //version

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.project {
            name 'xxxxx' //package name
            description 'A library for updating SQLite database in android.'
            url 'xxxxx'
            inceptionYear '2016'

            packaging 'aar'
            groupId 'xxxx' //group/org id
            artifactId 'xxxx' //your android module name
            version '0.0.1'

            licenses {
                license {
                    name "The Apache Software License, Version 2.0"
                    url "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt"
                    distribution "repo"
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id  'xxxxx' //developer username
                    name 'xxxxxx' //developer name
                    email 'xxxxxx@gmail.com' //developer email
                }
            }
            scm {
                connection 'xxxxxx' // YOUR GIT REPO
                developerConnection 'xxxxxx' // YOUR GIT REPO
                url 'xxxxxxx' // YOUR SITE

            }
        }
    }
}

Properties bintrayProperties = new Properties()
bintrayProperties.load(project.rootProject.file('bintray.properties').newDataInputStream())

bintray {
    user = bintrayProperties.getProperty('user')
    key = bintrayProperties.get('key')
    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = 'xxxxxx' //Bintray repository
        name = 'xxxxxx' //Bintray Package name
        userOrg = 'xxxxx'
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        vcsUrl = 'xxxxxxxx'
        publish = true
        version {
            name = '0.0.1' //version
            desc = 'xxxxxx' //Description
            released = new Date()
            vcsTag = 'v0.0.1'
        }
    }
}
```

After this open the android terminal below in your android studio and enter this command

./gradlew install

- if there is some errors you can append the command with --debug and re-enter the command to trace the error

//if nothing else fail issue this command
./gradlew bintrayUpload
*again if there is an error you can use the command and append with --debug to trace it.

after all these you will recieve an email or something and then you can proceed to downloading your library in other projects. Happy coding!